# memcached causes Apache processes to hang indefinitely

Tags: apache-2.4, memcached, strace, php-memcached

I have been tracking down the source of Apache processes hanging indefinitely. Unfortunately, I need to regularly reboot Apache as it eventually exhausts all slots. The Apache status page below shows processes hung in the `W - Sending Reply` state - and they will never die and just build up until ServerLimit is reached.

[image]

I ran `strace -ff -p {pid}` on an Apache process until it eventually hung in the "W - Sending Reply" state, and below is the strace output (I've removed non-pertinent strace output):

```
connect(13, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(11211), sin_addr=inet_addr("XXX")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 10)  = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(13, "get mcalls_e7e0891d35db253e26a31"..., 45, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 45
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "END\r\n", 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 5
sendto(13, "get trc-mods.197194\r\n", 21, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 21
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "END\r\n", 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 5
sendto(13, "set trc-mods.197194 5 1659718696"..., 2799, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 2799
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "STORED\r\n", 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 8
sendto(13, "get uonline_1354585\r\n", 21, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 21
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "END\r\n", 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 5
sendto(13, "get grps_1354585\r\n", 18, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 18
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "VALUE grps_1354585 5 6\r\n\0\0\0\2\24\0\r\n"..., 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 37
sendto(13, "get trc-mods.197129\r\n", 21, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 21
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "END\r\n", 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 5
sendto(13, "set trc-mods.197129 5 1659718696"..., 2308, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 2308
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "STORED\r\n", 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 8
sendto(13, "get trc-modcats.8279\r\n", 22, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 22
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
sendto(13, "set trc-modcats.8279 5 165971869"..., 318, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 318
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
sendto(13, "get trc-mods.211005\r\n", 21, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 21
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "VALUE trc-modcats.8279 5 277\r\n\0\0"..., 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 314
sendto(13, "set trc-mods.211005 5 1659718696"..., 2149, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 2149
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(13, "STORED\r\nEND\r\nSTORED\r\n", 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = 21
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
recvfrom(13, 0x556c1ea68810, 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
```

Based off this output, I believe the issue relates to memcached.

`/var/log/messages` shows these errors accumulating around the time of the hung process build up:

```
Aug  5 15:27:43 myhost memcached[3752802]: Failed to write, and not due to blocking: Broken pipe
Aug  5 15:27:43 myhost memcached[3752802]: Failed to write, and not due to blocking: Broken pipe
Aug  5 15:28:02 myhost memcached[3752802]: Failed to write, and not due to blocking: Broken pipe
```

Another thing I've noticed is when these hung processes build up, they build up at the same time on all 3 Apache servers (See below). The cliffs represent Apache reboots, and the hung processes are just beginning to build up again at the time of the screenshot.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this, or have any suggestions on what I can do?

Specs:

- AlmaLinux 8.5
- Apache 2.4.37
- PHP 8.1.4 with PECL Memcached 3.2.0 and libmemcached-awesome 1.1.1
- memcached 1.6.15 (daemon)

Comment: Althou this does not answer your question, but you should try php-fpm instead of running php as an apache/httpd module.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am considering this, however I have noticed php background tasks launched via crontab also occasionally hanging indefinitely for the same reason, so I don't think there is a guarantee switching to php-fpm will eliminate the problem. In a way it is also may be easier to reboot httpd via cronjob every 2 hours than try to kill hung php-fpm processes.

Answer (score 1):

After a week of trial and error, I think I finally resolved the issue, though I say this cautiously as I monitor the Apache status page for hung processes, because I've tried so many things that haven't worked.

My solution doesn't address the underlying problem which I believe may be a bug in libmemcached or php-pecl-memcached.

My solution was to buffer memcached `set()` and `delete()` calls within my application and run them at once at script shutdown using `register_shutdown_function()`, rather than littering them throughout various classes and running them in real-time alongside `get()` calls.

There are a few gotchas to this strategy (race conditions etc), so if you try it, test your code carefully. I should add that this approach makes a good opportunity to use `setMulti()`, however, apparently this method was never properly implemented in php-pecl-memcached (it just runs a loop of `set` calls).

[This discussion](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/458) was really helpful to understand what might have been happening in my case.